# SELECT query takes too much time even for a single record out of 165 total records in the users table

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I’m running a SELECT query inside PgAdmin. The table has 165 records in total, out of which, I’m trying to print a single record. But it takes 1.5s to execute (taking 3-4s sometimes). Previously, it’d take 5-6s but then I removed the bloat using VACCUM FULL command. It is preventing optimization in my APIs because every API hit (even for a single record) takes 4-5s from POSTMAN. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. That being said, there may be something wrong on your postgreSQL server or its network connection. Is it overloaded? This kind of query should be very fast.

Comment: Apart from the query plan I'd also be interested to see if the query is just as slow when run from psql (use `\timing`). Could be we're seeing some delays introduced by pgAdmin here.